# How to solve the differential equation $Ay''+ B(y')^2+gy=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation $Ay''+ B(y')^2+gy=0$?
I tried almost everything but nothing works.
Can I consider this as a Bernoulli equation and if yes, how to solve it?

Comment: @Moo but $y$ would be $\int p$ which complicates things.

Comment: The trick for autonomous second order DE is to set $y'=p(y)$ so that $y''=p'p$. But $Ap'p+Bp^2+gy=0$ is also not much more helpful.

Comment: I voted to close this as I'd like more details about the "almost everything" remark!

Answer (score 2):

Let $y'=p(y)$; then
$$
y''=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}p=\frac{d}{dy}
\left(\frac{p^2}{2}\right). \tag{1}
$$
Defining $u=p^2$, one may rewrite the ODE as
$$
\frac{A}{2}\frac{du}{dy}+Bu+gy=0, \tag{2}
$$
which is a non-homogeneous linear equation. I believe you can continue from here without difficulty.